# complex sql query in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I have 4  major tables in my database.

1. Season --> seasonID
2. Trials --> trialID
3. Competition --> CID,name
4. Camps --> campID,DivisionID(FK)
5. Divisions ---> DivisionID
6. Contestants --->ContestantID

Now a contestant belongs to / are members of a divisions.

Then a division belongs to a camp.

All this leads to my Performance table.

**PERFORMANCE TABLE**

```
SeasonID|TrialID|CampID|DivID|CompetionID|CtestantID|Score1 |Score2 |Total
1           1        1    1       1          1         20      20     40
1           1        1    1       2          1         20      15     30 
1           2        1    1       1          2         10       5     15
1           2        1    1       2          2         5        5     10
1           2        1    1       1          1         10      30     40
1           2        1    1       2          1         20      10     30
```

How can I query this performance table to give me the competition name, total score and rank (ranking over total score) of each contestant in each competition by trials and by seasons?

Example:

In season 1 and trial 2 I want to have:

```
 SeasonID| TrialID | ContestantID| Competition | TotalScore | Rank
   1          2           1            1            40         1
   1          2           2            1            15         2
   1          2           1            2            30         1
   1          2           2            2            10         2
```

How do I go about this? I have tried table variables, pivot and joins but I can only rank by competitions, but I don't how to aggregate the results to get the result above!

Comment: *I have 4 major tables in my database ... 1, 2, 3, ... 6*

Comment: @ta.speot.is: People don't have to be able to count nowadays, they have computers for that. :)

Comment: yea...tnx...guess we get so lazy @ times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how you calculated your desired results.  I think this is what you are after but, if so, the `TotalScore` in the desired results of your question should be 10 for the last record, not 20.

```
SELECT SeasonID, TrialID, ContestantID, CompetitionID, Total,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CompetitionId ORDER BY Total DESC) AS [Rank]
FROM PerformanceTable
```

Comment: yes...you are right...the total score for the last record is 10..just changed it..